# Sum in MySQL when a specific condition is met

Tags: mysql

I want to sum price from below table when order item is matched(in MySql).
Table 1-

```
Customers.  OrderItem. Price
Customer A.  Pizza.         300
 Customer B.   Pizza.       500
 Customer A.    Pizza.      200
  Customer B.    Pizza.      300
  Customer A.     Softdrink.  50
   Customer A.    Softdrink.    20
   Customer B.     Softdrink.    30
   Customer B.     Softdrink.    60
```

To get a new table like this:-

```
     Customer.    Pizza.   Softdrink
       Customer A. 500.     70
        Customer B. 800.     90
```

In MySql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Customer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN OrderItem = 'Pizza'     THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS Pizza,
    SUM(CASE WHEN OrderItem = 'Softdrink' THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS Softdrink
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Customer;
```

[image]

### Demo